# How do I initialize a VideoView globally? (outside of the onCreate) Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a video background in my sign in/login activity (similar to Spotify and other apps). I followed this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLwQ3SJjWfY

but I had to initialize my video background (VideoView) within my onCreate, because I couldn't figure out how to do declare it globally.

Therefore my onPause and onDestroy methods can't access it.

I can declare it certain ways inside my onCreate but once I do it globally I get an initiation error.

This is the way I'm doing it in my onCreate and it works fine
    var videoBG = findViewById(R.id.videoView)

I've tried to do these globally:

```
var videoBGGlobal:VideoView
var videoBGGlobal = VideoView(this)
var videoBGGlobal: VideoView = VideoView(this)
var videoBGGlobal: VideoView? = VideoView(this)
var videoBGGlobal: VideoView = null as VideoView
var videoBGGlobal = null //and then tried to assign videoBGGlobal = 
//videoBG within the onCreate but it says VideoView isn't type Nothing?
```

and I've tried more but I forgot the rest.

```
package ...
imports ...

class MainActivity {

//Global variables
var videoBGGlobal: VideoView = VideoView(this) //this just doesn't
var mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer() //this works
var mCurrentVideoPosition: Int? = 0 //this works

override fun onCreate() {
     var videoBG = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView) //here it //works
     }
 override fun onPause(){
    //need to access videoBGGlobal here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lateinit` to promise Kotlin you're gonna initialize the variable before accessing it for the first time:

```
class MainActivity {

  private lateinit var videoBGGlobal: VideoView

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    videoBG = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct version of all your attempts is:

```
var videoBGGlobal: VideoView? = null
```

But as Egor's answer says, this is the use-case for [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables):

> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property inside the body of a class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define videoview by lateinit var like

```
lateinit var mVideoView: VideoView
```